# Error while passing to the constructor

Tags: java

Why am I getting a red underline error when I try to pass arguments to the constructor, i.e. to create an object? What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CreateShape temp = new CreateShape(3,3, 'a', 
                {{'x','.','.'} 
                {'.','.','x'} 
                {'x','.','x'}}, "x . .\n"
                          + ". . x\n"
                          + "x . x");   
        temp.rotateCW();
        System.out.println(temp);
public CreateShape(int height, int width, char dc, char[][] charLayout, String layout)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.dc = dc;
        this.shape = charLayout;
        this.layout = layout;
        initialPos = Rotation.CW0;
    }
```

Im doint somthing wrong by writing arguments for `char[][]`.

Comment: Missing commas to separate the rows in the 2d array

Comment: ... and also missing `new char[][]` part: `new char[][] {{...}, {...}, {...}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the method rotateCW and the fields are all declared in the class.

When defining a 2-D array, the array is read as an array of an array. In a 1D array, we use {entry,entry}. Similarly in a 2D array, {{entry,entry},{entry,entry}}. Also, an array is an object and must be constructed as so.

Your problem is that you don't have the array constructor and there aren't commas between the arrays... So the array should be defined as:

```
new char[][]{
   {'x','.','.'},
   {'.','.','x'},
   {'x','.','x'}}
```

and then the rest of the arguments as usual.

Answer (score 0):

char array must be seperated using commas in 2d. This will work for You I guess

```
CreateShape temp = new CreateShape(3,3, 'a', 
                new char[][]{{'x','.','.'}, 
                {'.','.','x'}, 
                {'x','.','x'}}, "x . .\n"
                          + ". . x\n"
                          + "x . x");
```